# What are the dependecies to run and test Mule Facebook connector in local Anpoint Studio?

Tags: facebook, mule, mule-studio, connector

I have downloaded Mule Facebook Connector source code from https://github.com/mulesoft/facebook-connector. When I import the project in my Anypoint Studio, Several class names are showing errors due to imported classes not available in the application. Could someone please confirm what are the dependencies I need to add to compile, install and run the Facebook connector in my local Anypoint Studio?

My objective to to explore the connector coding and build a connector of my own.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Regards,
Rupesh Sinha

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to download and compile the connector yourself. Just install the latest version in Studio:

[image: Selecting Anypoint Connectors Update Site]

Reference: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Installing+Connectors

Comment: Hi David, Thanks for your response on this. My intention is to uninstall the existing Facebook connector, compile the Facebook connector source code downloaded from Git Hub, install locally and then use that in an application. I am trying to understand how the connector has been built and then work on my own connector for my client requirement. Please help me with details.

Comment: In that case, you need to build the connector with Maven, which will both create the connector artifact (which you can refer to in your project's POM) and generate a local Eclipse update site (which you can use to add the connector to Studio).